# SQL Statement to Join Users and Last Login Date,Location

Tags: sql

I have two tables, a list of Users, and a UserLoginHistory table that has their history of login dates, IP Addresses, and Geolocations.
I want to create one SQL statement that will return one each User + their last LoginDate and Geolocation.

```
  Users.UserId, Users.Name
     100        Bill
     101        Steve

  UserLoginHx.UserId, UserLoginHx.LoginDate, UserLoginLocation
    100               1/1/2018               New York
    101               1/1/2018               Los Angeles
    100               1/4/2018               Chicago
    101               1/5/2018               Denver
    ....
```

Result desired in this example should return two rows as:

```
    100  Bill  1/4/2018   Chicago
    101  Steve 1/5/2018   Denver
```

Thanks. (so far nobody got close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
select UserLoginHx.UserId,users.name,a.logindate,a.location from UserLoginHx
inner join 
(select UserLoginHx.UserId,max(UserLoginHx.LoginDate) as logindate
from UserLoginHx
group by UserLoginHx.UserId)a on a.UserId=UserLoginHx.UserId and a.logindate=UserLoginHx.LoginDate
inner join Users on Users.UserId=UserLoginHx.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.UserId, u. Name, ulh.LoginDate, ulh.UserLoginLocation
FROM Users u
JOIN UserLoginHistory ulh ON u.UserId = ulh.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

so for you  need `join` two tables

```
SELECT u.*, uh.LoginDate, uh.UserLoginLocation
FROM Users u
JOIN UserLoginHistory uh ON u.UserId = uh.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
with cte as
(
select a.*,LoginDate,UserLoginLocation,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.UserId order by Login desc) rn   
from Users a 
join UserLoginHistory  b 
on a.UserId=b.UserId
)select * from cte where rn=1
```

SQL Server